# How to lock a cell per-user for editing in LibreOffice Online Calc

Tags: cloud

Is it possible to lock a cell for editing for particular user in [LibreOffice *Online* Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-online/) / [Collabora *Online* Calc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collabora_Online)?

(similar question to [How to lock a cell for editing in LibreOffice Calc?](https://superuser.com/questions/900050/how-to-lock-a-cell-for-editing-in-libreoffice-calc) and [Trying to lock down cells in excel & office 365](https://superuser.com/questions/722553/trying-to-lock-down-cells-in-excel-office-365))

Comment: Note, there is no tag `libreoffice-online` (nor `collabora-online`).

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried including a brief description of efforts for finding the required info on the official docs.

Comment: @Rubén it's a general question if it's supported. BTW this site does not have `libreoffice-online` nor `collabora-online` tags, can you create one of them?

Comment: LibreOffice Online Calc is not a complete web app as it doesn't include several features that a web app should include so I'm not sure that it's on-topic. I suggest you to post a question on [meta] proposing the tag usage guidance / excerpt and wiki as well why you think that it's on-topic here.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's a general question"? Questions on this site should be specific and IMHO should include what was tried and a brief description of the efforts made by the OP to find the answer / solution.

Comment: I have searched but didn't find anything in the docs. Is this function supported? Or is this kind of question forbidden?

Comment: As I mentioned previously, please show what you tried. The description of the efforts to finde the required info on the official docs should be more descriptive that "didn't find anything" specially when the question is about a open-source component of a web app.